# How to take unique of a list in a DMN?

Tags: dmn, signavio

I want to take unique of all the elements in a input list to a decision.

For that I am trying to utilize the following FEEL functions in my DMN decision https://cloud.trisotech.com/help/index.html?dmn_feel_functions.htm, but it seems like only the following list of functions are available https://documentation.signavio.com/suite/en-us/Content/process-manager/userguide/dmn/use-literal-expressions.htm.

Does anyone have any idea where i can use the above functions in my DMN. I am trying to write FEEL in 'Expression' tab of my decision.

Answer (score 1):

DMN specification provides a built-in List function to select distinct elements in a feel:list, it's called `distinct values()`.

Example:

```
distinct values([1,2,3,2,1]) = [1,2,3]
```

as taken from the DMN specification.

You can use this in any literal expression for instance, or everywhere a FEEL expression is allowed.

Example:
[image: DMN modeling example]

This model, once executed, would result in:

```
{
  My decision : [1,2,3]
}
```